# Session Authentication Token Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

I am relatively new to integrating APIs into Swift. I have a login page and I am trying to authenticate a user and create a session when they sign in. I found a code online that supposedly works for a lot of people, but I am having trouble actually getting the whole thing to work. I have concluded that something is going wrong beginning near this line which you will see in the code below because at the line before it I am able to get the auth token.

```
if let data_block = server_response["accessToken"] as? NSDictionary
```

I am including all of the relevant code and I would like to know what is going wrong, how to successfully authenticate and create the session, and get the segue to actually work.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    _login_button = "Login"

    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard

    if(preferences.object(forKey: "session") != nil)
    {
        LoginDone()
    }
    else
    {
        LoginToDo()
    }

}


@IBAction func signIn() {


    let username = emailLoginTextField.text
    let password = passwordLoginTextField.text

    if(username == "" || password == "")
    {
        return
    }

    if(_login_button == "Logout")
    {
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        preferences.removeObject(forKey: "session")

        LoginToDo()
        return
    } else {
        DoLogin(username!, password!)
    }    
}

func DoLogin(_ user:String, _ psw:String)
{
    let url = URL(string: "http://agile-castle-10059.herokuapp.com/authentication")
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let paramToSend = "username=" + user + "&password=" + psw + "&strategy=" + "local"

    request.httpBody = paramToSend.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data else
        {
            return
        }

        let json:Any?

        do
        {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        }
        catch
        {
            return
        }


        guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
        {

            return
        }

//problem occurs around here, nothing happens (assuming the data_block isn't being created for some reason)

        if let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String
            {
                let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")

                DispatchQueue.main.async (
                    execute:self.LoginDone
                )
            }
        }

    })

    task.resume()

}


func LoginToDo()
{
    _login_button = "Login"
}

func LoginDone()
{
     self.shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: "showHomeViewControllerFromSignIn", sender: self)
    _login_button = "Logout"
}
```

Comment: what is the actual problem?

Comment: The actual problem is that nothing is actually happening. So when I break the code before the data block part, i can see the server_response has a token. However, I need the session to be created and something is going wrong there because nothing happens when running the full code.

Comment: What does the content of `server_response` look like at the point where you see the token?  Also, try using the debugger to step through the logic so you don't have to *assume* what's happening.

Comment: @PhillipMills server_response contains  - key : accessToken
    - value : eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6ImFjY2VzcyJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJ5ZElTWk44T1VHcFJJRFNDIiwiaWF0IjoxNTI1NzEwNDI3LCJleHAiOjE1MjU3OTY4MjcsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8veW91cmRvbWFpbi5jb20iLCJpc3MiOiJmZWF0aGVycyIsInN1YiI6ImFub255bW91cyIsImp0aSI6ImY3MWFlODhhLWYwZDctNDY5Mi1hMDk2LWUzOTkzNTJmYjA1MyJ9.QadWtLiX4nmYfz1zegU1_U7nhVdhRK7e-okrBeVOw8Q               so basically ["accessToken":"1234567"]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a few things and figured it out

```
 guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
        {
            return
        }


            if let session_data = server_response["accessToken"] as? String
            {
                let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "accessToken")

                DispatchQueue.main.async (
                    execute:self.LoginDone
                )
            }


    })

    task.resume()

}
```